# PHP reading from file multiple lines, different first words

Tags: php, string, file, fopen

I am trying to read from a txt file in php. I am able to open the file and properly display it line by line, but I want to make a decision based on the first word. For example, if in the text file the line started with:

Something1: This is a test

It would output that string but "Something1:" would be bold and a color different then

Something2: This is a test2

Which would also be bold and a color. SO lets say I want everything tagged "Something1:" to be outputted bold and red but I want everything "Something2:" to be outputted bold and green. Is there anyway to do that.

```
$file = fopen($message_dir, "a+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while (!feof($file))
{
    if (strpos(fgets($file), "Something1") == 0)
    {
        echo "<font color='#686868'><b>".fgets($file)."</b></font><hr />"."<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<font color='#fc0c87'><b>".fgets($file)."</b></font><hr />"."<br />";   
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

This is the direction I was heading but I'm sure there is an easier way more efficient way. First of all this bolds and colors the whole sentence and second of all I think fgets auto increments or something because it does the if statement right but then it prints the next line instead of the one it did the if statement for. But that was my first thought, check to see if the word is at position 0 of the string.

Comment: Why are you opening the file in append mode? You could just use `'r'` as the mode.

Comment: How many lines are in the file btw? Is it alot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that `fgets()` reads another line every time you call it, so you need to save its value in an intermediate variable if you wish to reuse it:

```
$line = fgets($file);

if (strpos($line, 'Something1') === 0) {
    $format = '<font color="#686868"><b>%s</b></font><hr /><br />';
} else {
    $format = '<font color="#fc0c87"><b>%s</b></font><hr /><br />';
}

echo sprintf($format, htmlspecialchars($line, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Also, you're opening the file in append mode, but you never write to it:

```
$file = fopen($message_dir, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get yours to work but then I noticed the if statement had === and once I added that it worked. Thanks for the tip about the append mode, the reason is because the appending will be coming next, I was just focusing on the reading first

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from the file into a buffer variable, every time you read from a file you get new data, the preceding ones get "lost" in your case.

```
$file = fopen($message_dir, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while (!feof($file))
{
    $currentLine = fgets($file);
    if (strpos($currentLine, "Something1") == 0)
    {
        echo "<font color='#686868'><b>$currentLine</b></font><hr /><br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<font color='#fc0c87'><b>$currentLine</b></font><hr /><br />";   
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

I would not use the font tag etc, but rely on css:

```
$file = fopen($message_dir, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
echo "<ul>\n";
while (!feof($file))
{
    $currentLine = fgets($file);
    if (strpos($currentLine, "Something1") == 0)
    {
        echo "<li class="Some1">$currentLine</li>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<li>$currentLine</li>\n";   
    }
}
echo "</ul>\n";
fclose($file);
```

Since you are outputting a list, I would use an unordered list and formatting trhough css like this one:

```
ul > li {
    color: #fc0c87;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none;
}

ul > li.Some1 {
    color: #686868;
}
```

With appropriate changes to the `ul > li`  rule you can leverage the css to adapt the appearance better that with a hr/br tags.